# Is this an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

I would like to ask if the words "Grain Honey Nut" in "Grain Honey Nut Cheerios" are adjectives or not. If not please can someone tell me what word class it is?

Answer (score 1):

The word "Grain" is part of the two-word adjective ["Whole Grain"](https://wholegrainscouncil.org/definition-whole-grain). I don't think there is [any such product](http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/calories/general-mills-whole-grain-honey-nut-cheerios-cereal-only-16980564) as "Grain Honey Nut Cheerios".

In a similar way, I would parse the two word phrase "Honey Nut" as a two-word adjective.

So, all told, I'd parse the name of the cereal like this:

> <sub>adj                               adj                      noun</sub>
>   **[Whole Grain] [Honey Nut] [Cheerios]**

Incidentally, when a word that is usually a noun functions as an adjective (as do *chicken* and *paper* in the phrases *chicken soup* or *paper clip*), this is knows as a [**noun adjunct**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: See more on this construction at: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154421/what-is-it-called-when-two-or-more-nouns-comes-in-a-row/154426#154426